# Error coming as undeclared identifier 'buy'; and undeclared identifier 'sell'

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

code

```
//@version=4 
strategy("Sagargy1") 
fast=20
slow=50 
fastMA= ema(close, fast) 
slowMA= ema(close, slow) 
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=close[0] > close [1] and fastMA > slowMA and close[0]>vwap) 
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, 10, when=close[0] < close [1] and fastMA < slowMA and close[0]<vwap) 
plot(Buy, color=color.green) 
plot(Sell, color=color.red)
plot(Buy, color=color.green)
plot(Sell, color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected ur code, u can see it here https://www.tradingview.com/x/oERRUXom/, you dont need to add zero after close as this refer to last last candle in chart. closer zero means close

```
//@version=4 

strategy("Sagargy1", overlay=true) 
fast=20, slow=50 

fastMA= ema(close, fast) 
slowMA= ema(close, slow) 

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=close > close [1] and fastMA > slowMA and close>vwap) 
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when=close < close [1] and fastMA < slowMA and close<vwap) 


plot(fastMA, color=color.green) 
plot(slowMA, color=color.red)
```